# mercurial: can't push. Why am I getting "pretxnchangegroup hook exited with status 1"?

Tags: windows, mercurial

All of a sudden I can't push to my mercurial repo on codebase: (I am running Windows)

```
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 2 changesets with 2 changes to 1 files
remote: transaction abort!
remote: rollback completed
remote: abort: pretxnchangegroup hook exited with status 1
```

There are no hooks running.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Looks like the hook is running on the remote repository. Do you have access to the remote's file system to see if a hook is defined there?

Comment: It looks like hooks are disabled. I have access via codebase.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenter points out.  There is a hook running -- it's just on the server side.  Talk to whomever admins that system and tell them if it output something to stderr saying why it was rejecting the push you'd be in much better shape.  It could be a misbehaving email-notify on the server side, or a check for ACLs, or a check for valid whitespace, or anything else they've configured, but there's definitely a hook on the other end.

Comment: Thanks very much! Is there any way i can see the errors or hooks myself? I have full access to codebase. This is a project that has changed hands many times so I have a hard time tracking sown what was done. Thanks!

Comment: Hooks can't be "disabled".  You either have them configured (on the server -- you won't find these locally) or you won't.  On the server side they could be in a number of places: `$(hg root)/.hg/hgrc` or `/etc/mercurial/...` or the **server** user's `$HOME/.hgrc`.  On the server, running and the user that's running the hg process (might be a system user or "you") try `hg showconfig | grep hook`

Comment: I mean there is:

`$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;`

in config.php

Comment: That is a php setting and Mercurial is a python application.  That settings has absolutely nothing to do with and no effect upon Mercurial.